# Most efficient way to render object of lists, containing objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Pretty new to React, currently trying to render out the below object which comes as a prop. It's an object containing lists, containing objects.

What's the most efficient way to map over it, and return the below html for a component?

I keep running in to trouble using `Object.entries()`

```
prop = {     
    list1 = [
        { 
            id: 1,
            value: "some value 1"
        }, 
        { 
            id: 2,
            value: "some value 2"
        }
    ], 
    list2 = [
        { 
            id: 3,
            value: "some value 3"
        }, 
        { id: 4,
            value: "some value 4"
        }
    ]
}
```

desired html:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <h1>List1</h1>
    <ul>
      <li key={id}>
        some value 1 
      </li>
      <li key={id}>
        some value 2
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>List2</h1>
    <ul>
      <li key={id}>
        some value 3 
      </li>
      <li key={id}>
        some value 4
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what problems are you having with `object.entries`

Comment: Looking at the below, I was not passing an array into the to .map function - so Object.entries(lists).map( (object , item ) => { ... })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a generic `List` component and pass your `list1` and `list2` as a prop.

```
// List.js

import React from "react";

export default function List({ items, title }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      {items.length > 0 && (
        <ul>
          {items.map((item) => (
            <li key={item.id}>{item.value}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

And assuming you're passing object of list to the `App` component as a prop, then your App.js should look like

```
// App.js

import "./styles.css";
import List from "./List";

export default function App({ lists }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <List items={lists.list1} title="List1" />
      <List items={lists.list2} title="List2" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[**CodeSandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-frost-6pm69?file=/src/App.js:0-229)

EDIT:

Updated answer using `Object.entries`

```
// App.js

import List from "./List";

export default function App({ lists }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {Object.entries(lists).map(([title, items]) => (
        <List key={title} items={items} title={title} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to loop over the prop to extract the title and items? I will not always know the key names of the lists in advance? I assume a merge of your solution and Yuriy Yakym's ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.entries` for getting an array of key-value pairs of lists. You can also split it into smaller components to make code more readable.

```js
return (
  <div>
    {Object.entries(lists).map(([listName, listEntries]) => (
      <div key={listName}>
        <h1>{listName}</h1>
        <ul>
          {listEntries.map((entry) => (
            <li key={entry.id}>
              {entry.value}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```